# In TypeScript, how do I map each value of a union to a separate type?

Tags: typescript

Let assume I have a `FruitName` like this:

```
type FruitName = "banana" | "apple"
```

But I also have context types like `BananaContext` and `AppleContext`.

I would like map `"banana"` to `BananaContext` in such a way that I can do:

```
const context: ContextOf<"banana"> // This would be BananaContext
```

How do I do that?

Comment: How about `type Contexts = {apple: AppleContext, banana: BananaContext}` and then `const context: Contexts['banana']`?

Comment: Thanks Kaya. The problem is that I couldn't obtain a context by doing `Contexts[anyFruitName]` because I don't know how to guarantee that `Contexts` would have one key per `FruitName`

Comment: You can simply define `type FruitName = keyof Contexts` and then it's guaranteed, and also you avoid duplication.

Comment: Kaya I guess that would indeed work. I hadnt thought of inverting the problem and extracting `FruitName` from `Contexts`. If you would like to provider an answer, I will accept it. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a lookup type like so:

```
type FruitContexts = {
    apple: AppleContext,
    banana: BananaContext,
}

type Test = FruitContexts['banana'] // BananaContext
```

To avoid code duplication, it is then a good idea to define `type FruitNames = keyof FruitContexts` so that there is only one place in the code that needs to be changed in order to add or remove a fruit type.